# How can I root my Orange Hi 4g (ZTE Blade Apex 2)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access

I search a lot can I can't find any useful method to root the ZTE Blade Apex 2. Someone says that the bootloader is unlocked. Is that true? If it's true, can I install CyanogenMod using the CyanogenMod Installer?

Comment: Which are you actually trying to do: root your current ROM, or install Cyanogenmod?

Comment: I was trying to find the root first, backup some things, and later install CyanogenMod. On my others experiences with Android I've always root first and later install CyanogenMod, in fact a lot of CyanogenMod funcionality requires root.

Comment: I've just get working the root with [Qitu Root](http://www.7to.cn/root.html). Thanks to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDL_x6aTjDA&feature=youtu.be) wich explains step by step the root process.